# how to wait for writeFile or createWriteStream function to complete in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am stuck in code I tried different way to wait for write file in node.js but it does not wait .

Below is code

```
app.post('/createEmp',async (req,res) => {
    console.log("Inside createEmp()");
    var response = await createEmp(req.body);
    console.log(response);
}); 

async function createEmpFile(fileContentObj){

    var response = {};
    console.log("filePath :"+filePath);
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fs.writeFile(filePath, fileContentStr, function (err) {
          if (err){
            console.log("err :"+err);
            reject(err);
          } 
          else {
            console.log('Saved!');
            fileSavedFlag = true;
            response.result = fileSavedFlag;
            console.log(response);
            resolve(response)
          };

        });
    }); // end of promise

    /*return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
        file.write(fileContentStr)
        file.end();
        file.on("finish", () => { fileSavedFlag = true; resolve(response) }); 
        file.on("error",  () => { resolve(response) }); 
    }); */

}
```

On node js console I can see response but when I called using postman I dont get any response it

Comment: There is no any `res.send(res)` line in your code.If only you will receive response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post route should have `res.send` as follows

```
app.post('/createEmp',async (req,res) => {
    console.log("Inside createEmp()");
    var response = await createEmp(req.body);
    console.log(response);
    res.send(response)
});
```